# Advantages of Stream and Spring Data

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-data

Some people override the CrudRepository's method findAll to return an Stream (java 8), but I saw they finally transform the Stream to a List in order to send it through a rest controller. Why are they using a Stream ? What is the advantage to use a Stream here? If they want to filter the records I think would be better filter on DataBase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is already supported in Spring Data JPA, look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming); so there's not real advantage to override those to return `Stream`.  If you really want a `Stream` and some potential advantages that would come with it - use what already Spring Data JPA provides.

And also a different aspect is that in `JPA Spec 2.2` this could be the default return type of some queries. The JPA interfaces `Query` and `TypedQuery` will get a new method called `getResultStream()`.

So Spring Data will use techniques specific to a particular provider, like `Hibernate` or `EclipseLink` to stream the result.

By default `getResultStream` is just a `list.stream` implementation, but `Hibernate` already overrides that with `ScrollableResult`. This is way more efficient if you need to process a very big result set.

Comment: You'd know of a blog article showing how all of this can be put into action ?

Comment: @Stephane sorry, I dont.

Comment: @Stephane did you find some resource to show all that in action ?

Comment: @humbleCodes No I haven't worked on this

Answer (score 2):

Providing it as a `Stream` gives the repository consumer the choice on how to collect the data.
In addition it allows chaining/piping of operations on the stream, such as mapping to DTOs, augmenting data, and filtering.
If the only thing you're ever going to do is collect it to a list and send as a response, then there is no benefit.

But take for example the case where a `Thing` repository returns a `List<Thing> findAllThings()` of `n` `Things`s because most of the time it's just sent as a list via the API.
But then someone builds a service in the application that needs to filter only `Things` that exist in another set of `m` `Things` in the application.
We would have to recreate a list filtering on the set like

```
List<Thing> acceptedThings = repo.findAllThings()
                                 .stream()
                                 .filter(t->set.contains(t))
                                 .collect(toList());
```

So we've had to iterate the original list and reconstruct a new list.
If there are further operations on this list, you can see how it may be sub-optimal.

If the response from the repository had been `Stream<Thing>` then we could have chained the filter operation and passed on the Stream for any further processing.

```
Stream<Thing> acceptedThings = repo.findAllThings()
                                   .filter(t->set.contains(t));
```

Only right at the end when something consumes the stream will execute all the operations relevant for each item.
This is much more efficient as each element only needs to be visited at most once and no intermediate collections need to be created.

Given that Spring now supports returning Streams as `@ResponseBody`'s in controllers, it's even better.

Comment: Are you sure of usage .map() for filtering? contains() returns boolean and then .map() would return boolean too.

Comment: @horvoje yeah you're right :) Not sure what I was doing there. Will update! thanks

Answer (score 1):

There might be various reasons why people want to use `Stream`s.

1. If you do any processing that you can't or don't want to do in the database, `Stream`s might be nicer to work with.
2. It's so hip and "functional". Almost everybody still seems to be experimenting what the right combination of features is. So it is perfectly possible and even likely that there is no benefit in using `Stream`s. But then, it doesn't cost much either.

Answer (score 1):

You should see these options as a way to improve your *programming model* only, from imperative style JDK `List` to a more functional style stream. You should still push down as much logic into the SQL query to benefit from indexing, better execution plans, etc. If your `Stream.filter()` is simple, then it can be expressed as a SQL / JPQL `WHERE` clause.

Please use SQL (or JPQL if it suffices) whenever querying the database. Don't filter in the client if you can avoid it. That would be like buying the entire produce in a super market, throwing everything away, just to get a single yoghurt.