# Can JPA stream() cause OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: spring, jpa, stream

In my Spring MVC project, I have used pagination where I fetch too many records from tables.

Currently, I have planned to use [JPA Stream](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-java-8) instead.

Like below:

```
Stream<User> findAll();
```

I don't collect them to list or search for max value. I just need to operate on each value (forEach) on the stream.

**Can it cause** `OutOfMemoryError` **if table has too many records ? (Say, more than 10 million)**

Comment: The `Stream<User>` will result in a lazy cursor and fetch only that amount of records as specified by the JDBC fetch-size. It will not put all records into memory like you do with a `List<User>`. So unless you are holding onto the `User` object somewhere memory should be released periodically.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for your answer. I will accept it if you post. There is one more thing which I am worrying about: Does db cache all results of the query while I fetch them (In that case it could cause problems in db). Or does it perform query several times each fetching data with amount of rows which are equal jdbc.fetch_size?

Comment: Here is my fetch size: `<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">1000</prop>`

Comment: How things are habndled on the DB side, probably depends on both thd database used, the amount of data and the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Hibernate as a JPA provider the `Stream<User> findAll()` will result in a lazy cursor (see [this question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642556/advantages-of-stream-and-spring-data)). This means it will only fetch the amount of records that is specified by the JDBC fetch-size. It will not put all records from the database (if there are more then 1000) into memory, like what happens with a `List<User> findAll()`.

So unless you are holding onto the `User` object in your code and collect them into a collection/array the memory should be released periodically.

Comment: That's not true because these objects will be collected in first level cache in memory. The only difference is that for `List` all of them will be hydrated and put into the cache at once, while for `Stream` there will be fetched some amount of them and put into the cache. But finally the first level cache will contain all 1000 objects. So it can end up with out of memory.

Comment: According to this blog post you also have to detach the entities to avoid them sitting in the cache once processed https://www.geekyhacker.com/2019/03/26/high-performance-data-fetching-using-spring-data-jpa-stream